# How capture nested groups?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a target string like this: (however nesting can be very deep in practice)

`{hi {how {are {you}}}}`

Desired result would be:

Groups:
`hi` `how` `are` `you`

I can't find anything in c# regex to do nested capturing like that. Is it possible at all?

**EDIT**:

I think I simplified my example too much which obscures the answers.
I need to capture in a recursive sort of way because I need the content inside the brackets:
`{test[{test2[content]}]}`

where the desired result would be:

`{test2[content]}` and `content`

Comment: what you expect? simple string as a result?

Comment: `[^{}\s]+` or `[a-z]+`

Comment: The input will have only { and } ?

Comment: Is `{a{b}c}` possible?

Comment: Avinisah, a cool way to think, but my real example would be something like this: {test[{test2[content]}]} where it would need to match everything inside the [], but only with that syntax. I dont think your example can be adapted to that example, this is mostly why i asked in general on how to capture nested things.

Answer (score 0):

```
{([^{}]+)
```

Try this.See demo.grab the captures.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/35

Comment: Sorry, I was asking for a general way on how to capture in a nested fashion. Your solution happens to work on this example, but it won't for pretty much any non trivial recursive capturing problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of this:

```
 string balh = "{hi {how {are {you}}}}";
 string[] foo = balh.Split(new char[] { '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 string output = string.Join(" ", foo);
```

The groups will be in `foo` array.

**EDIT:**

I think you are looking for more elaborate inputs. I got the question wrong :(